# Multiple modules within one git repository; only one module needs to be deployed to Heroku

Tags: node.js, git, heroku, github

I have a project that has, at the moment, 2 npm-modules. One module will run on Heroku, while the other module will run on a client. Both modules are written in Node. Right now, they are in different repos, but I'd like to put them in the same repo.

They are independent of each other, but designed to interact with each other, so I'd like to have them in the same repo, since they are components of the same project.

The problem is Heroku pushes everything in the repo that isn't ignored by the gitignore-file, but I don't want the client module to just lay around on the server.

Is there a way of telling Heroku that I just want one npm-module deployed, but not the other?

Maybe with git submodules or some other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to break 12factor architecture (http://12factor.net/), which I wouldn't recommend. If the modules are in fact independent, their source should be maintained separately, rather than in the same repo.

However, you can do what you're trying to do. Put the package you want to keep into package.json's "dependencies" list, and put the other package into package.json's "devDependencies" list. With Heroku's default `NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=true` setting, the "devDependencies" won't be installed.

Also, keep in mind that having an extra module "lay around on the server" is not a problem. Unless you `require` the module, it won't impact memory at runtime, so your app will behave identically whether or not it's available on the filesystem.

Comment: I'll accept this answer; I ended up keeping them seperate.